# From 'a' to Qt.Key_A in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm sure it's basic, but I've searched and came back empty-handed.
I'm using Python 3.6.4 and `PyQt5`.
I want to store some custom action keys in a config file (via `configparser`), and then retrieve them and respond to that keypress event.
So basically I'm looking for a function in PyQt5 that performs the reverse of `chr(Qt.Key_A)` - from a character, returns a Qt.Key_.
I couldn't help myself with Googling this time, and PyQt5 is huge to peruse. I was wondering if someone could point me to the right direction.
I could use a dict, but I'm sure there must be a function that does it - I'm just not finding it.

Comment: `QKeySequence('Ctrl+A')`.

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks... It's a good workaround but I was hoping to actually get a `PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.Key` object, for cleanliness. QKeySequence  will give me a `PyQt5.QtGui.QKeySequence` object, which I can work with, but eh, it's just one step better than having a dict. But it's a good hint, I'll check if there's  a way to get a `.Key` object from there.

Comment: It's not a work-around. It's the [public api qt provides](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#details) for managing shortcut key combinations. I think you're missing the point that `QKeySequence` provides a round-trip parser for human-readable key sequences defined as strings (which are absolutely perfect for saving in config files). By contrast, you are trying to hard-code opaque enum values that have no guaranteed fixed values. Thus, it's your attempted solution that looks like the work-around - although what you are actually trying to work around is unclear.

Comment: @ekhumoro indeed it's my first rodeo with PyQt. It's a pity that this is not the correct medium, otherwise I'd really profit from reading more from you... I'll educate myself better, though. But in short, I thought that since every keypress event resulted in a `Key` object, while I would only load the config once, then if I converted the config into `Key` objects, I wouldn't have to perform any more conversion calls e.g. from `Key` to `QKeySequence`. I see your answer and as much I understand the idea, definitely there's something I'm missing in the way I handle this. I'll look around, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to store the keys as ASCII code with `ord()`, since they can be directly compared to `Qt.Key_` objects:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
ord('A') == Qt.Key_A
Out[2]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about alphanumeric keys only, `getattr(Qt, f"Key_{key.upper()}"` should work.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

def string_to_key_converter(s):
    attribute = f"Key_{s.upper()}"
    if hasattr(Qt, attribute):
        return getattr(Qt, attribute)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Key {s} is invalid or unsupported.")

> string_to_key_converter("a") is Qt.Key_A
>>> True
```